# Access the value of a disabled field in a twig template

Tags: theming, 8, paragraphs

I'm using the [Paragraphs module](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) to create components, i then make a content type and add the Paragraph as a reference field.

The form of the Paragraph has a field (a list) where a content creator can select a color name for a background color for the div. Each Paragraph has 3 values (pacific_blue, smokey_white, white).

However, i'm trying to get the selected value without displaying it on the site.

As long as the field is not disabled i can get the value using this code and add the class to style the div with the right background color:

```
<div class="c14a {{ content.group_wrap.field_color_backgroud.0["#markup"] }}">
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
      {{ content }}
  </div>
</div>
```

So how do i get the value of a field that is disabled in 'manage display'?

Thx...

Comment: I update my answer with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i going to answer my own question because i think it's the most elegant option for my current situation.

The solution is to **'not' disable any field**. Then in your template you just output the fields that you want. That way, you do have the value but you are not outputting it to the visitor.

```
<div class="c14a {{ content.field_background.0["#markup"] }}">
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>

    {{ content.field_title }}

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it on you [hook_preproccess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.2.x) to variables.

something like following snippet could help you.

**on your THEMENAME.theme**

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    $node = $vars['node'];
    if(isset($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->getType()=='YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME') {
        $values = $node->field_color_backgroud->entity->getValue();
        $vars['myvar'] = $values[0];
    }

}
```

Then on your TWIG file `{{ myvar }}` will be available.

Comment: `Try to get it via node` I doubt this will work since paragraphs is its own/separate entity (not part of node). So `content.field_color_backgroud.0.getvalue` or `paragraphs_item.field_color_backgroud.0.getvalue`

Comment: @NoSssweat yep, you right, I don't consider he ask about paragraph type . Thanks for your note ,I'm going to  update my answer

Comment: What's the 'requested_course' string?

Comment: @kevinius Oops, it was my content type machine name :D .  I update  it to `YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME`

Comment: @kevinius adding type filtering prevent error on other content types, because this fields maybe not available on other content types.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on your self-answered question, if you're using Display Suite and Paragraphs together and want to keep your formatting and any special token fields you've created, the `without` twig filter works great for excluding any fields you don't want to show. Here's my custom template that uses a couple of fields as CSS classes, then hides them from display:

```
<{{ ds_content_wrapper }}{{ attributes.addClass('ds-1col', 'clearfix') }}>
  {{ title_suffix.contextual_links }}
  {% set bgcolor = content.field_background_color.0['#markup'] %} 
  {% set angles = content.field_skew.0['#markup'] %} 
  <div class="wrapper {{ bgcolor | lower }} {{ angles | lower | replace({' ':'_'}) }}">
     {{ ds_content | without('field_background_color', 'field_skew') }}
  </div>   
</{{ ds_content_wrapper }}>
```